# Editing isolinux leads to kernel panic error in Centos Live CD

Tags: centos, livecd, kernel-panic

I downloaded a CentOS Live CD and tried to customize features on it. The CD boots fine if I use it "as-is". If I edit "isolinux.cfg" to edit the change the title of the CD or the automatic boot time, I get the following error:

```
    Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
Pid: 1, comm: init Tainted: G     W  --------- 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1
Call Trace:
...
...
```

Is there a file integrity check that runs before boot that is causing the error? The same does not happen with a Fedora Live CD.